# WiFi on Lenovo ideapad running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I have a lenovo ideapad laptop. I installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 in it and the WiFi works really bad. It randomly work fine, disconnects by itself, sometimes doesn't show the available WiFi networks, and even when I get a connection it eventually disconnects.

Is there any known problems, and solutions, for this ?

The output of the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

These newer Atheros wifi cards do not work well with power management enabled.  You can disable power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot